# Create Observable that emits asynchronously

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I want to create an `Observable` that detects *things*. These are discovered in time and aren't available when the Subscriber subscribes. How do I approach this?

My attempt was to create an Observable as so:

```
Observable.create(new AsyncOnSubscribe<Object, Thing>() {
    @Override
    protected Object generateState() { return null; /* state not presented for the sake of simplicity */ }

    @Override
    protected Object next(Object state, long requested, Observer<Observable<? extends Thing>> observer) {
        if(haveMoreThings()) {
            while (!nextThingAvailable()) {
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
            }

            observer.onNext(Observable.just(getNextThing());
        } else {
            observer.onCompleted();
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

This works but is a no-go since there are some issues I cannot figure out:

**First problem**
How do I check that the observer hasn't unsubscribed? Using the deprecated `Observable.create()` one could do:

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            if(subscriber.isUnsubscribed()){
                // stop detecting things
            }
        });
```

**Second problem:** Whats the proper way to wait until something is available (within the observable)? Is `SystemClock.sleep(x);` the way to go?

**Design question:** It might be easier to just use a `Subject` for this but I don't have enough exp with rxJava to justify this opinion. In case this is the way to go it'll be awesome if an example was provided.

Comment: First of all, Observable work the other way around. It calls you, not the other way around. The Observable will start emitting values, when you subscribe to it. Every time you subscribe to it, a new pipeline will be created. Could you please provide more information about the "thing" api. Does it have a async api or do you have to poll for the information?

Comment: @HansWurst sorry for not clarifying that. The things are polled from an async source that is handled manually. The Observable created will be returned to the caller that is asking for several things. The code provided will be the mechanism that provides the things, for this reason it will return an Observable.

Comment: Go with your design idea. A `Subject` both **subscribes** to the *thing* detection and **publishes** those *things*. `Subject`s also enforce the correct unsubscribe behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It still isn't clear what you are trying to do. You likely do not need to create an observable, but use `Subject` instead.

```
PublishSubject<Thing> thingDetector = PublishSubject.create();

// detector loop
while ( true ) {
  Thread.sleep( 100 );
  if ( haveAnItem ) {
    thingDetector.onNext( next() );
  }
  if ( allItemsDone ) {
    thingDetector.onComplete();
  }
}
```

Since you don't specify how you interface with the thing, I can't be more specific.